# Calculate amount of available heap memory in Java

Tags: java

I have the following details of a Java process (WildFly application server):

```
 "heap-memory-usage" => {
            "init" => 536870912L,
            "used" => 73683328L,
            "committed" => 505413632L,
            "max" => 1908932608L
        }
```

I need to create an alert when the amount of free memory drops under a certain level. Is it correct to assume that the heap **available memory** equals to (**max - used**) ? or should I use (max - committed) ? 
Thanks

Comment: google "*java get free memory*" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807797/java-get-available-memory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206847/exact-state-of-committed-memory-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use max - used. See `java.lang.management.MemoryUsage` class API for details